# Moshi JsonAdapter for (desugared) java.time.LocalDate is not recognized

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, moshi

I have an Android app, and I'm trying to transition from ThreeTenABP to the Java 8 "time" APIs that are supported by [Android Gradle Plugin 4.0 through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Here is my custom Moshi adapter

```
@Keep
internal class DateTimeAdapter {
    @ToJson fun toJson(@DateTimeTimestamp dateTime: LocalDateTime): Long {
        return dateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    }

    @FromJson @DateTimeTimestamp fun fromJson(dateTimeTimestamp: Long): LocalDateTime {
        return localDateTimeOf(dateTimeTimestamp)
    }
}

@JsonQualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
internal annotation class DateTimeTimestamp
```

Here's how I supply it while building the Moshi instance

```
   fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
        return Moshi.Builder()
            .add(DateTimeAdapter())
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
    }
```

And here's how I use it in one of my DTOs

```
@Keep
data class ErrorDto(
    @Json(name = "timestamp") @DateTimeTimestamp val date: LocalDateTime?,
    @Json(name = "status") val statusCode: Int,
)
```

However, at runtime, I get this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class java.time.LocalDateTime requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
```

The same exact adapter works fine with the org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime. That is, the application doesn't crash and the Long timestamp is successfully turned into LocalDateTime